# forçar autoplay em player de audio

Tags: javascript, jquery

com a nova atualização do chrome a função `autoplay` do audio não funciona, gostaria de saber como forçar o autoplay, ja tentei assim:

```
document.getElementById("controles").setAttribute('autoplay', true);
```

Assim:

```
$("#controles")[0].autoplay = true;
```

E assim:

```
var controles = document.getElementById("controles");

function enableAutoplay() { 
    controles.autoplay = true;
    controles.load();
}
```

E nenhum jeito funcionou, alguém sabe por que?

Comment: Qual a marcação em html desse player ?

Comment: @Atila Silva `<audio src="kalimba.mp3" autoplay id="controles"></audio>`

Comment: O atributo `autoplay` direto na tag não funcionou ? Está a testar em desktop ou mobile ?

Comment: @Isac não funcionou de nenhum jeito, estou a testar em desktop

Comment: Coloque a forma como tem o `html` para se conseguir perceber se o erro vem dai

Comment: não entendi oque vc quis dizer

Comment: O arquivo `kalimba.mp3` que está a tentar carregar existe ? Está na mesma pasta que o arquivo html ? Funciona em outros navegadores ? O html indicado por si `<audio src="kalimba.mp3" autoplay id="controles"></audio>` funciona sem necessitar de javascript sequer, por isso o problema vem de outra coisa

Comment: na verdade, onde ta a musica kalimpa.mp3 no lugar vai um streaming, sim em outros navegadores funcionam, ele nao funciona só com o `autoplay` por isso precisei forçar, mesmo assim não está tocando, e problema no streaming não é, porque ele toca em outros navegadores, menos no chrome